# Intelligently Fill Bootstrap Columns with Background Color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, regex, twitter-bootstrap

For grid mockup purposes I am trying to write an intelligent script that will read my html markup which contains bootstrap classes such as col-md-x etc. For visual aid during development and design I would like all columns to have a background color and some space added to fill out the grid so they can see how the grid is stacking etc.

My first approach is the following:

**A tagging system**

By adding certain classes these are used as "tags" to flag what type of content the grid would be serving. So for example:

```
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-8 content"></div>
         <div class="col-md-4 sidebar"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

These classes would have a set background color and height for the typical space that these grid columns would take up.

While it works, I feel that this may not be 100% scalable and that there is probably a better way to automate this.

I am wondering if there could be a similar approach by using jQuery/Javascript to set background colors to all divs with the class of col-x-x. This would set the background color so that the grid is technically visible for example purposes. Then have Javascript somehow set fixed heights for divs automatically. This part is where I am stuck and I keep coming back to the tagging system to flag it's type.

Comment: using jQuery and css selector you can set a height to all : $('col-md-8').css('height', 200);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery, you can easily do something like this -

```
$('div[class*="col-md-"]').css('background-color', 'blue');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/474197md/) for your example.

You can also set any number of properties you want there, like so -

```
$('div[class*="col-md-"]').css({'background-color': 'blue', 'color': 'white'});
```